# Django loop through all items to save, but it only saves one record

Tags: python, django

I have next model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Salary(models.Model):
    id_of_people=models.ForeignKey(People)
    salary = models.IntegerField(required=False)
```

In views.py

-When I try this one:

```
    for each in People.objects.all()[:3]:
            Salary().id_of_people_id=each.id
            Salary().save()
```

It only saves 3 Th id, not from 1 to 3. So, it only saves one time. But, I want to loop through all 3 records, why this happens ? How to add all People table id's to Salary table ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. `Salary` is a model, not an instance. You would have to actually get or create an instance of Salary before you can save it.

Comment: I am sorry, I forget to put that. I have edited it, Please consider this edited version...

Comment: Why is the `for each` line indented?

Comment: Because, I loop through all items from my People table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're creating a single Salary object and updating it three times. You need to create three separate objects.

```
for each in People.objects.all()[:3]:
    item_salary=Salary()
    item_salary.id_of_people_id=each.id
    item_salary.save()
```

Comment: @themanatuf what if we want to do it same in model using def save() and we need to keep loop inside the save function?

Comment: Just do the same as mentioned by @themanatuf